# Collections.sort is not sorting anything

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm trying to sort a String array in a short, simple way.
I'm trying to use Collections.sort, but I don't understand why it doesn't sort anything.
Code:

```
public static String[] FishNamesSorted;
.....
List<String> nameslist = new ArrayList<String>();
nameslist.toArray(FishNamesSorted);
Collections.sort(nameslist, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); <--- NOT WORKING

Collections.sort(nameslist, new Comparator<String>() { <--- NOT WORKING
    @Override
    public int compare(String p1, String p2) {
    if (p1 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (p2 == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    return p1.compareToIgnoreCase(p2);
    }
});
```

Results in both cases:

- Poecilia Latipinna
- Poecilia Reticulata
- Notropis Chrosomus
- Pseudomugil Gertrudae
- ....

Whyyyy?

Comment: are u using `List<String>`,  post your code?

Comment: What's the type of `nameslist`?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. `Collections.sort` definitely *does* work in general...

Comment: What is `FishNamesSorted`?

Comment: In the example you have given you are not adding anything to `nameslist`, so you are sorting an empty `List<String>`.

Comment: Have you tried just sorting the original `FishNamesSorted` array using `Arrays.sort(FishNamesSorted, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`?

Comment: Arrays.sort(FishNamesSorted, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) does everything I need :) 
Now I don't understand why I read everywhere that people were encouraged to use Collections.sort...

Comment: @BeritLarsen It works if you use it correctly. If *jmcg* is right with the assumption that you're thinking that `FishNamesSorted` will also be sorted by the `Collections#sort` call (after "exporting" the list to the array), then you should definitely re-read what `#toArray()` really does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was

```
Arrays.sort(FishNamesSorted, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

I had misunderstood how it works

Answer (score 6):

`Collections.sort(list)` definitely works. The problem in your code is **you placed the list into the array before sorting**. The array should be sorted if you sort your list first before putting it to the array

```
List<String> nameslist = new ArrayList<String>();

/* add elements to namesList */

Collections.sort(nameslist);
Object[] fishNamesSorted = nameslist.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to put your `nameslist` in your `FishNamesSorted` array only after it is sorted, which you are not doing right now.

have a look,

```
    String[] FishNamesSorted;

    // creating and initializing list,
    List<String> nameslist = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding some data in your list
    nameslist.add("Poecilia Latipinna");
    nameslist.add("Poecilia Reticulata");
    nameslist.add("Notropis Chrosomus");
    nameslist.add("Pseudomugil Gertrudae");

    // sorting your list,
    Collections.sort(nameslist);

    // print sorted list
    for (String s : nameslist){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    System.out.println("===================");

    // convert the sorted list to an array and assign it 
    // a String array.
    FishNamesSorted = nameslist.toArray((new String[nameslist.size()]));

    // print your String array,
    for (String s : FishNamesSorted){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

just FYI, you can make your sorting process work even faster if you are using Java 8.

Java 8 provides an API for sorting any type of array using `Arrays.parallelSort(type)`, it performs sorting the same way as `Collection.sort` but with a parallel implementation.

> Current sorting implementations provided by the Java Collections
>   Framework > (`Collections.sort` and `Arrays.sort`) all perform the sorting
>   operation sequentially in the calling thread. This enhancement will
>   offer the same set of sorting operations currently provided by the
>   Arrays class, but with a parallel implementation that utilizes the
>   Fork/Join framework. These new API's are still synchronous with regard
>   to the calling thread as it will not proceed past the sorting
>   operation until the parallel sort is complete.

to implement it, replace `Collections.sort` with `Arrays.parallelSort` in the above code,

replace,

```
Collections.sort(nameslist);
```

with,

```
Arrays.parallelSort(nameslist.toArray(new String[nameslist.size()]));
```